# Odd jQuery Variable-Passing Behavior

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to pass a variable to a hidden form input upon click of a button like so:

```
        $('#convertToButton').click(function() {
            $("#currencySelectValue").val($("#currencySelect").val());
            $("#currencyValue").val($("#fromCurrencyValue").val());
            $.post("php/convertToForm.php", $("#convertToForm").serialize(), function(data){ 
                $('#toCurrencyValue').val(data);
            });
        });

        $('#convertFromButton').click(function() {
            $("#currencySelectValue").val($("#currencySelect").val());
            $("#btcValueForm").val($("#btcValue").val());
            $.post("php/convertFromForm.php", $("#convertFromForm").serialize(), function(data){ 
                $('#fromCurrencyValue').val(data);
            });
        });
```

In the first click handler, everything is passed fine. In the second click handler, the form does not show as having had passed `#currencySelectValue`. The code is the same, so I'm not sure where the problem lies.

Here are the forms:

```
<form action="php/convertToForm.php" id="convertToForm">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $last; ?>" name="lastPrice" id="lastPrice"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currencySelectValue" id="currencySelectValue"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currencyValue" id="currencyValue"/>
<!-- get values of the currency selector, and the currency value -->
</form>
<form action="php/convertFromForm.php" id="convertFromForm">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $last; ?>" name="lastPrice" id="lastPrice"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currencySelectValue" id="currencySelectValue"/>
<input type="hidden" name="btcValueForm" id="btcValueForm"/>
<!-- get values of the currency selector, and the BTC value -->
</form>
```

Everything but the `#currencySelectValue` in the convertFromForm is passed fine. Any help?

Comment: where are your convert buttons please post more code probably you have to change the id to class or use distinct ids in the DOM for different currencySelectValue or use the FormName to access the right one.

Comment: Might want to post your rendered html and js to http://jsbin.com/ and link to it from here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should **never** have multiple elements with the same IDs throughout your document. IDs must be unique to work.

If you want to select copies or similar sections, use classes instead.

Comment: I changed the names to be unique, although I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: jQuery will only grab the first reference of the id if there is multiple.